# Cefsharp Custom Prompt

Tags: cefsharp

How can i make custom Prompt?
I tried with code below..

```
public static string ShowDialog(string text, string caption) {
        Form prompt = new Form() {
            Width = 500,
            Height = 150,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog,
            Text = caption,
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
        };
        Label textLabel = new Label() { Left = 50, Top = 20, Text = text };
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox() { Left = 50, Top = 50, Width = 400 };
        Button confirmation = new Button() { Text = "Ok", Left = 350, Width = 100, Top = 70, DialogResult = DialogResult.OK };
        confirmation.Click += (sender, e) => { prompt.Close(); };
        prompt.Controls.Add(textBox);
        prompt.Controls.Add(confirmation);
        prompt.Controls.Add(textLabel);
        prompt.AcceptButton = confirmation;

        return prompt.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK ? textBox.Text : "";
    }
```

And then am using it like below

```
public bool OnJSDialog(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, CefJsDialogType dialogType, string messageText, string defaultPromptText, IJsDialogCallback callback, ref bool suppressMessage) {

        if(dialogType.ToString() == "Prompt") {

            //Form prompt = ShowDialogClass.ShowDialog("as", "asd");
            string promptValue = Components.ShowDialog("Test", "123");
            if (promptValue != "") {
                callback.Continue(true, promptValue);
            } else {
                callback.Continue(false, "");
            };

        };
```

But i am getting error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.'

        return false;
    }
```

How can i implement this dialog to show custom prompt?

Comment: Are you using `WinForms`? If so add the relevant tag.

Answer (score 0):

Few months too late but, here you go.
You are trying to create a new Form(your prompt form) inside another thread. In this case your CEF browser thread that will create a object from class IJsDialogHandler will be on another thread than the prompt message thread so you have to Cross the thread to access it.
The way you do this is "Invoke"(saying something like "wo wo don't worry, i know what i'm doing"). When you use "Invoke" your asking for a witness, well that witness should have the same kind of capabilities as your prompt message box form so.... in this case form that creates the CEF browser. so the code should be something like this

```
public bool OnJSDialog(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, CefJsDialogType dialogType, string messageText, string defaultPromptText, IJsDialogCallback callback, ref bool suppressMessage) {

    if(dialogType.ToString() == "Prompt") {
        if (ParentForm.InvokeRequired)
        {
            ParentForm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                string promptValue = Components.ShowDialog(messageText, "Prompt Message");
                if (promptValue != "") {
                    callback.Continue(true, promptValue);
                } else {
                    callback.Continue(false);
                }
            }
        }
        suppressMessage = false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
ParentForm
```

should be changed to the name of the form that initialize the CEF browser.

Comment: You can cast IWebBrowser to ChromiumWebBrowser and access invoke directly without having to pass in a form reference.